# Jquery mobile unable to get latitude and longitude

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, gps

I'm trying to get current location in my mobile app using Jquery. I followed this tutorial and i copied  the sample. I saved the file as .html file and try to open from my phone. The code unable to get the current Latitude and longitude.

Display current GPS coordinates

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
  <link rel=stylesheet href=jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile.css />
  <script src=jquery.js></script>
  <script src=jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile.js></script>
</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role=page id=home>
  <div data-role=header>
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role=content>
    <span> Latitude : </span> <span id=lat></span> <br />
    <span> Longitude : </span> <span id=lng></span> <br />
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<script>

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (pos)
{
  var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
  var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
  $("#lat").text (lat);
  $("#lng").text (lng);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Samsung hardware is known for problems with navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition. For example, I have galaxy S2 and S3 and both of them can't get getCurrentPosition function to work.

Answer (score 0):

You did not write what kind of phone you are testing on.
But I tried this once on iPhone, where it did not work.
On iOS you need to enable locationservices for the app's. Locationservices is under Settings->General.

That being said I did not go through your script to see if there are any issues there, but I tried it in jsfiddle and it worked fine for me on desktop.

Comment: i'm testing on galaxy nexus. android version 4.2.1.

Comment: Do you get the popup with question about allowing site to get your position?
Also if you have the page somewhere public, then paste a link and I can give it a try on some of my devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. This is working for me ... Also it should upload to a server. Will not work on localhost..

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
      var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
      var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
      if (lat == null) {
        alert("GPS not activated");
      }
   });
});
```